# Twig is not loading in Silex

Tags: twig, silex

I'm trying to run application with [Silex FW](http://silex.sensiolabs.org). I have similar source code as in example:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/silex.phar'; 

$app = new Silex\Application(); 

$app['debug'] = true;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/views',
    'twig.class_path' => __DIR__ . '/vendor/twig/lib',
));

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($name) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('hello.twig', array(
        'name' => $name,
    ));
}); 

$app->run();
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error:  Class 'Twig_Environment' not found in phar:///var/www/silex/silex.phar/src/Silex/Provider/TwigServiceProvider.php on line 40
Stack trace:
  1. {main}() /var/www/silex/index.php:0
  2. Silex\\Application->run() /var/www/silex/index.php:20
  3. Silex\\Application->handle() phar:///var/www/silex/silex.phar/src/Silex/Application.php:396
  4. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handle() phar:///var/www/silex/silex.phar/src/Silex/Application.php:411
  5. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handleRaw() phar:///var/www/silex/silex.phar/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:72
  6. call_user_func_array() phar:///var/www/silex/silex.phar/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:128
  7. {closure}() phar:///var/www/silex/silex.phar/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:128
  8. Pimple->offsetGet() phar:///var/www/silex/silex.phar/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:15
  9. {closure}() phar:///var/www/silex/silex.phar/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:81
 10. Silex\\Provider\\{closure}() phar:///var/www/silex/silex.phar/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:120
```

This problem was also [posted on GitHub](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/issues/252).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) and [`autoload.php`](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/issues/252#issuecomment-5045152).

Answer (score 0):

With that approach, your twig.class_path probably needs to be `vendor/twig/twig/lib` (extra twig directory) ...

But twig.class_path is actually unnecessary, with composer, which is the better approach (as kuboslav notes).